# asparallel plinq vs linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a code block

```
var result = db.ProductReceives.Where(x => x.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt)).ToList();
```

works fine but when i write same query

```
 var result = db.ProductReceives.AsParallel().Where(x => x.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt)).ToList();
```

It Shows a error message
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I want to execute the query AsParallel query.can some one help?

Comment: yap. but not a single clue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hit the database as `db` suggests, then:

- The non-parallel code will be translated to a SQL query and executed by the DBMS directly.
  This is *fast*. Especially if you have an index on `CustomerName` as it'll be able to only scan through that index (you'll end up with a full table scan otherwise but it will probably *still* be fast enough).
- The second one will:

  - *Download* the whole `ProductReceives` table. All of it.
  - It will then create an object for each row.
  - Then it will feed these objects to your parallel check.

  This *will* be *much* slower than the first solution.

You're getting a `NullReferenceException` because one of these rows has a `NULL` `CustomerName`. So you end up calling `((string)null).ToLower()`.

The error doesn't occur in the first case because the DMBS will take care of filtering that out by itself.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should check customer name null or not before call ToLower.

```
db.Tv_ProductReceive.AsParallel().Where(i =>i.CustomerName != null && i.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt)).ToList();
```

Comment: May be you did not under stand my problem.AsParallel() not working but simple where is working?